# Alignment of Multiple Div inside div

Tags: html, css

[image]I have this kind of structure.

```
<div id = "div">
    <div id = "div1">
        <div id = "div11"></div>
        <div id = "div12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id = "div2">
        <div id = "div21"></div>
        <div id = "div22"></div>
        <div id = "div23"></div>
        <div id = "div24"></div>
        <div id = "div25"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For div2 I want all inside div have to come in line.

I want like this struuectue

[div21] [div22] [div23] [div24]

and 5th div has to come down to all four div.

I tried with float left and right, postion but I am not able to do that.

Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what this is supposed to look like? do you have an image of the required result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#div21,#div22,#div23,#div24{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Actually width is different for first 4 divs.

Comment: Give the four div's [div21] [div22] [div23] [div24] display:inline-block

Comment: @AnitaMehta you should make a fiddle with the content.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AnitaMehta/nk05wn3j/, this is the fiddle, it is totaly breaking, what ever width, height I am giving, I am getting from the VD

Comment: Don't give float when you are giving inline-block.

Comment: tried but not working, I have added the image, how I want, please check and let me know,  I have given my code also in jsfiddle link

Comment: Your fiddle is confusing. Just give the basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bootstrap rows and columns method. Download the bootstrap css file from [this website](http://getbootstrap.com). Link the css file with your code and then you can try this:

`<div id = "div">
    <div id = "div1">
        <div id = "div11"></div>
        <div id = "div12"></div>
    </div>
    <div id = "div2">
    <div class="row">
        <div id = "div21" class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div id = "div22" class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div id = "div23" class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div id = "div24" class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id = "div25" class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>`

The width of the div can be changed by changing the values in col-md-3. The range of values will be 1-12. But in a row div the total size should be 12.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
#div2 {
  display: flex;
}
#div2 > div {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 .25em;
}
#div25 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <div id="div21"></div>
  <div id="div22"></div>
  <div id="div23"></div>
  <div id="div24"></div>
  <div id="div25"></div>
</div>
```